# Big headsep values destroy my margins

Tags: formatting, header-footer, margins

I want to have a document where there is a gap of 5cm after the header. So I set the headsep to 5cm which just shifted the text down 5cm and not the bottom margin is way too small. Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{Nice right header}
\lhead{Nice left header}
\setlength{\headsep}{5cm}

\begin{document}
%A lot of text
\end{document}
```

As you can try out, if you have a lot of text in the document it just goes off the paper. How can I fix this? Maybe some command to have a \vspace{5cm} at the start of every page?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What you need to know is that `\headsep` isn't included in the `\textheight` and you need to decrease that by the amount you've added to `\headsep`.  (Of course fewer lines will fit on a page, and you may have to adjust page breaks.)  See the diagrams in this document to understand the parts of the page layout: https://texdoc.org/serve/layman.pdf/0

Comment: Thank you that works just like I want it to work. If you want you can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When modifying the default dimensions of a document's pages, it's helpful to understand how these dimensions are defined.

The user manual for the `layout` package describes this mechanism very well, with copious illustrations.  I'm not necessarily recommending *using* this package, but the illustrations in the manual are invaluable.  Look for the manual here:  https://texdoc.org/serve/layman.pdf/0

For actually adjusting page dimensions, the `geometry` package is most often recommended.

In the present case, what is most important is to understand that `\headsep` isn't included in the `\textheight`, so it's necessary to decrease that height by the amount added to `\headsep`.